# Is a surjective linear map T:P2(R)→R4 possible?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

We are learning about surjective and injective linear maps in the context of applications of the dimension theorem (if V is a finite-dimensional vector space and T: V → W is a linear transformation, then dim(Ker(T)) + dim(Im(T)) = dim(V)). As such we are discussing what types of linear maps are surjective and/or injective.

If T: P<sub>2</sub>(ℝ) → ℝ<sup>4</sup>, can the linear map ever be surjective?

When I approach this question, I know that dim(P<sub>2</sub>(ℝ)) = 3 and that dim(ℝ<sup>4</sup>) = 4. This follows:

- 3 = dim(P<sub>2</sub>(ℝ)) = dim(Ker(T)) + dim(Im(T))
- dim(Im(T)) ≤ 3 since dim(ker(T)) ≥ 0.
- dim(Im(T)) ≤ 3 < 4 = dim(ℝ<sup>4</sup>)

Therefore Im(T) ≠ ℝ<sup>4</sup> which means that T is not surjective.

Is there any possible situation in which the linear map T: P<sub>2</sub>(ℝ) → ℝ<sup>4</sup> can be surjective?

Comment: What do you mean with “any possible situation”? Is that when $T$ is *not* linear.

Comment: You are right. Since $\mathbb{R}^4$ has dimension strictly greater that $\mathbb{R}_2[X]$, then you cannot have such a surjective linear map.